# VBA Rounding Error - <Type Mismatch>

Tags: vba, excel, rounding

I am having a problem with the "round" function in VBA Excel. My code worked the other day, but I changed some data around in my spreadsheet and now I get an error. I have read just about every thread on the error, but everyone just says make sure your variable are the same type, which mine are.

Code:

```
Dim Fab1_Bag as Double
Dim rate as Double
Dim product_array(1 To 43, 1 To 6) as Double

If product_array(i, 1) = 1 Then
Fab1_Bag = Fab1_Bag + product_array(i, 4)
End If

Fab1_Bag = round(Fab1_Bag * rate, 1)
```

'The "product_array()" is pulling values from a spreadsheet in a previous loop.

Error:

```
Fab1_Bag = round(Fab1_bag * rate, 1) = <Type mismatch>
```

Comment: Did you try a break point before this line & check what's inside? O.o

Comment: Where is `rate` assigned a value and is that the **actual** code? The capitalisation looks off.

Comment: Yes I have. Fab1_Bag = 3.5 and rate = 7.5. Rate is assigned earlier as: rate = cph_entry.Value / 60. Where cph_entry is a text box.  Do you mean "round" should be "Round"? Every time I add the capital "R" it changes it to lowercase when I run it.

Comment: why in your code you have `round(Fab1_Bag * rate, 1)` and not `Round(Fab1_Bag * rate, 1)` ? are you using a variable somewhere with this name ?

Comment: If I type my code `Round(Fab1_Bag * rate, 1)` and run it, I get the error and my code has changed to `round(Fab1_Bag * rate, 1)`

Comment: That suggests you have a function or sub called `round` and it is not declared with the same argument types that you are passing here. If you use `VBA.Round` instead, do you still get an error?

Comment: I found the error! Thanks Shai for pointing me in the right direction. Rory you had it too, I just had not read your comment before I found the problem. I had a checkbox with the word "round" in the name which was a typo from the actual name. Fixing the name solved my problem ! Thanks guys!